# fwrite() and fread() don't work in C XCODE

Tags: c, xcode, file, fwrite

I noticed that fread() and fwrite() don't work in my programmes. I wrote this little one to demonstrate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Product {
    float size;
    float price;
} Product;

int main() {
    Product my_prod;
    my_prod.price = 13.2;
    my_prod.size = 10.3;

    FILE* file_in = fopen("/Users/piton/Desktop/UniverProg/Test/Test/input.txt", "w");
    if (file_in == NULL)
        printf("ERROR");

    fwrite(&my_prod, sizeof(Product), 1, file_in);
    
    fclose(file_in);
    return 0;
}
```

So, I have output in input.txt: ÕÃ$A33SA

(Yeah, I named file "input" but actually it is for output)

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You should use `"wb"` instead of `"w"` for open mode to deal with binary file.

Comment: What would you except to have in your file ?

Comment: Hmmm, the correct output should be `ÍÌ$A33SA` (`cd cc 24 41 33 33 53 41` in hex) according to [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

Comment: What happens if you read this content with `fread` and print it? What is content of that struct if you inspect the memory location?

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Looks like what you get is the correct output - the binary data (8 bytes) for your structure represented as their component, 1-byte characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you are implying that your file is a text file (input.txt), using the "fwrite" function with the output of a structure containing floating point variables will output the data using the number of bytes required to store a floating point value in a binary fashion.  For most C programs that will be four bytes.  So, using your program, I ran the program and then reviewed the raw hexadecimal data using a hexadecimal file viewer.  This is what I viewed.

```
CD CC 24 41  33 33 53 41
```

The eight bytes coincides with the length of two stored decimal numbers.  "CD CC 24 41" represents the value "13.2" and "33 33 53 41" represents the value "10.3".  To verify this I added a few lines of code to your program so that the program would read the data back in from the file and print out the values stored in that file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Product
{
    float size;
    float price;
} Product;

int main()
{
    Product my_prod;
    my_prod.price = 13.2;
    my_prod.size = 10.3;
    
    FILE* file_out = fopen("input.txt", "w"); /* I changed the name to file.out */
    if (file_out == NULL)
        printf("ERROR");
    
    fwrite(&my_prod, sizeof(Product), 1, file_out);
    
    fclose(file_out);
    
    FILE* file_in = fopen("input.txt", "r"); /* I then reopened the file to read */
    fread(&my_prod, sizeof(struct Product), 1, file_in);
    
    printf("Price: %f, Size: %f\n", my_prod.price, my_prod.size);
    
    fclose(file_in);
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran the program, here is the output from the data read from the file.

```
Price: 13.200000, Size: 10.300000
```

So the data was properly stored originally.

As noted in the comments, since data is being stored in a binary fashion, you might want to open the file as a binary file (e.g. fopen("input.txt", "wb")).

I hope that clarifies things.

Regards.

Comment: *you might want to open the file as a binary file* -> you **must** open the file as a binary file